# Password History

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

We have a requirement to prevent users from reusing the previous 5 passwords when doing the reset. I read in the documentation that currently, Azure doesn't support the password history feature. Is there any way I can implement it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample for [this](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/password-history).

"This policy enables the storing and checking of a user's previous set of passwords in order to prevent them from using a previous password during a Password Reset flow. The number of previous passwords is configurable in this example, and will default to 3 if not set".